# Tilda Отправка данных из самописной формы формы

Tags: php, form, tilda

Есть сайт на Tilda, на котором планируется разместить самописную форму. Tilda позволяет добавлять HTML, CSS и JS, но возможности добавить PhP нет.

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом я могу решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить php код нельзя. На офф сайте написано:

`Свой код PHP вставить на страницу не получится, но его можно добавить на свой сервер и отправлять на него данные с помощью приемщика Webhook.`

[Здесь написано как реализовать свой скрипт через webHook](https://help-ru.tilda.cc/forms/webhook)

[https://help-ru.tilda.cc.](https://help-ru.tilda.cc/html#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20PHP%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0,%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20Webhook.&text=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%20head,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8C%20head%C2%BB.)

Comment: С этим Webhook есть одно "НО". Он будет работать только со стандартным блоком формы от Tilda. У меня же будет использоваться блок для вставки кода.

Comment: @ElJeko  Ну по идее Вы же можете отправлять аякс запросы на свой сервер, верно?

Comment: @Simon могу. Что делать с PhP?)

Comment: @ElJeko положить его на своем сервере и обращаться к нему посредством аякс запроса.

Comment: @simon первый раз буду реализовывать такое. Есть хороший материал по этому поводу почитать/посмотреть?

Comment: Вопрос решен___